# Sorting excel pivot table by values

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I've just created my first excel pivot table. I can sort by zip code , but I want to sort by the values column but don't seem to have that option. How can I do this?

Comment: Right click on a cell in the "count" column and select the Sort option

Comment: Thank you, would you like to enter it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to Right click on a cell in the "count" column and select the Sort option